# VBA Prompt user to choose Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I used Macro Recorder in Excel to record a series of tasks I need to automate. These tasks happen between two different Excel spreadsheets. I believe that the macro performs the code on the current worksheet, but right now the second sheet is hard coded. How do I prompt the user to choose an Excel sheet to reference to?

The workbook that is going to have the macro is the `MasterHardwareDB` & the file that needs to be replaced with a user input is `Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx`

I was researching the filedialog object but I am not sure how to integrate here.

```
Sub AutomateCompare()
'
' AutomateCompare Macro
'
ActiveCell.Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX('Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[scheduleddate],MATCH([ @HostName],'Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[computername],0))"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("MasterHardwareDB[[#Headers],[Name]]").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX('Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[scheduleddate],MATCH([@HostName],'Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[computername],0))"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("MasterHardwareDB[[#Headers],[Name]]").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-1
ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Range("MasterHardwareDB[[#Headers],[Name]]").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX('Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[forecastdate],MATCH([@HostName],'Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[computername],0))"
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=1
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("MasterHardwareDB[[#Headers],[Name]]").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-7
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MasterHardwareDB").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, _
    Criteria1:="FALSE"
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=1
ActiveCell.Offset(4169, -4).Range("MasterHardwareDB[[#Headers],[Name]:[EmpID]]") _
    .Select
ActiveCell.Offset(521, 1).Range("MasterHardwareDB[[#Headers],[Name]]").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-7
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MasterHardwareDB").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, _
    Criteria1:="=Scheduled", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=To Be Scheduled"
ActiveCell.Offset(87, -8).Range("MasterHardwareDB[[#Headers],[Name]]").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=8
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600533/how-do-i-prompt-the-user-to-select-the-file-and-sheet-when-using-macro-to-impor) may be able to help you.  Check out the first answer, that should get you started.  Are you familiar with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is

```
shtNum = InputBox("Enter the number of the sheet you want to use.")
With Sheets(shtNum)
   Your code here
End With
```

Also, just so you know, macro recorder code contains a lot of junk.  Here is a cleaned-up version of your code.

```
Sub AutomateCompare()
With ActiveSheet
    'Change the ranges to what you need.  Using activecell is usually dangerous
    .Range("A1:A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[scheduleddate],MATCH([ @HostName],'Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[computername],0))"
    .Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[forecastdate],MATCH([@HostName],'Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[computername],0))"
    .ListObjects("MasterHardwareDB").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="FALSE"
    .ListObjects("MasterHardwareDB").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=Scheduled", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=To Be Scheduled"
End With
End Sub
```

Edit:  Here is code that opens another workbook

```
Sub AutomateCompare()
Dim fileBrowse As FileDialog
Dim shtNum As Integer
Set fileBrowse = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
If fileBrowse.Show = True Then wbPath = fileBrowse.SelectedItems(1)
With Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
    shtNum = InputBox("Enter the number of the sheet you want to use.")
    With .Sheets(shtNum)
        'Change the ranges to what you need.  Using activecell is usually dangerous
        .Range("A1:A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[scheduleddate],MATCH([ @HostName],'Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[computername],0))"
        .Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[forecastdate],MATCH([@HostName],'Computer&DeploymentInfo_06_23_15_v3.xlsx'!Table1[computername],0))"
        .ListObjects("MasterHardwareDB").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="FALSE"
        .ListObjects("MasterHardwareDB").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=Scheduled", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=To Be Scheduled"
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome.  It's confusing at first, but you'll get the hang of it.

Comment: Will InputBox work with choosing which excel workbook to use in this case? I need to replace the excel workbook path in the macro with the path of the file that is selected.

Comment: InputBox is best for choosing the sheet, but clunky for choosing the workbook.  You would have to have the user paste the path in.  I've edited my code to let the user select both the workbook and the worksheet.