# macro getting bugged while re run

Tags: vba, loops

Not able to re run below macro does anyone know why it breaks on file location ?

Also does someone knows how to loop this macro to pick up more sheets in to the workbook?
trying to pick up the sheets from workbook 2 and format them in below manner.

```css
Sub specalign()
'
' specalign Macro
'

'
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\\\\Interface Specifications Master v7 7.xlsx"
    Sheets("1.1.1").Select
    Sheets("1.1.1").Move After:=Workbooks( _
        "Interface Specifications Master v7.8.xlsx").Sheets(2)
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("N1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1:N1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Spec ID]]").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Spec ID]]").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("A4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 8
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    Range("A3:B3,G3:M3").Select
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[  Conditionality ]]").Activate
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 90
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Rows("3:3").RowHeight = 108.75
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 8#
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 8#
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 34#
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 22#
    Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 17#
    Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 8#
    Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 22
    Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 8#
    Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 8#
    Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 8
    Columns("L:L").ColumnWidth = 6#
    Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 10
    
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Did you remove folder names from your file location? you have lots of slashes which probably aren't helping.

Comment: Yes I removed the address,for the file name. Macro works well till selecting the file but after that

Answer (score 0):

going off of what @nickslash said your filename looks like it's this issue.
however, there are many things you can do improve this code like getting rid of the scrollcolumns and all the selections.

To get the file path you can right click on the file in your folder and select properties. > On the General Tab select location. Then you'll see the path you'll need.

As you learn vba you'll do better than what I've put here. and select files and make it more dynamic (maybe a prompt to select the file you want as jean demonstrates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559163/how-do-i-prompt-the-user-to-select-the-file-when-using-macro-to-import-a-data-f)).

**Update below:**

```
Sub specalign()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

'this is what mine looks like with the directory
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\james\Documents\Interface Specifications Master v7.8.xlsx") 'target workbook .8 I kept
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\james\Documents\Interface Specifications Master v7 7.xlsx")  'source workbook


For Each ws In wb2.Worksheets
    ws.Copy after:=wb1.Worksheets(2)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks James that looks better now, also could you tell if I want to make it a loop in all sheets of above workbook what should I use.

Comment: I mean copy the sheet from wb1 and then run the code to format in wb2 then repeat but copy the next sheet from wb1

Comment: yes you can do that by doing 
For each wks in Worksheets
     'some code here
Next

Comment: which one is the target and where are the sheets you want to copy.  so Interface Specifications Master v7.8.xlsx is the main and you want to copy all the sheets from Interface Specifications Master v7 7.xlsx?

Comment: Yes James,that is the goal

Comment: @AbhishekSharma updated to include the for each to import all the sheets in the source workbook